# Raising interior prehung door before installation?

Tags: doors, finishing

I am getting ready to install standard height interior prehung doors.  I will have carpet installed afterwards and would like to set the doors at a good "standard" height to prevent having 1.) a big gap under the door and 2.) hopefully not have to take doors off and cut them down.  Being a prehung door, it appears there is 3/4" of space already created due to the door jambs being longer than the slab.

I know I will have the best padding available for my carpet but I believe that is only 1/2" thick then a fairly soft (high shag) carpet which I would guess is 5/8 to 3/4" long carpet strands?...though I do not know for sure how that all can be used to calculate the door height for sure.  SO I was hoping there is a good standard to use assuming carpet will be installed under the door slab.

Answer (score 1):

Most places set the jambs on a scrap piece of 1/2" plywood, setting the bottom of the door at a minimum of 1 1/4" from the subfloor. If the subfloor is not level, make the lowest side a little higher, so the gap will be slightly bigger.

Comment: Thanks, Jack.  Is the idea to maintain at least 3/4" gap under the doors?  I have found this is "required" if you do not have air returns for each room.  However, I will have returns in the majority of my rooms, so I was shooting for a minimal gap.

Comment: The 1/2" shim under the jamb will just let the door go over the carpet without "sweeping" it. If it is a tall pile it may need to go up a little higher, perhaps another 1/8". But there will not be a 3/4" gap.